# What is an efficient way to REPLACE repeated elements within a 2D (10x10) int array

Tags: c, arrays

I have generated a 10x10 integer matrix, by way of a 2 dimensional array, the elements are randomly generated and lie on

```
1 <= z <= 5.
```

I am in need of an efficient method of setting all adjacent "duplicates" (repeating elements), along any row or column (not diagonally), of length 3 or greater to the integer six (6). The source for the brute method follows for clarity.

```
for(row=0;row<10;row++)
{
    for(col=0;col<10;col++)
    {
        board[row][col]=rand()%4+1; //filling matrix here
    }
}
print_board(board, row, col);

printf("Switch: ROW COLUMN\n ");
scanf("%hu %hu", &x1, &y1);
printf("With: ROW COLUMN\n");
scanf("%hu %hu", &x2, &y2);
swap(board, x1, y1,x2, y2);  //stdrd for loop no good b/c of
                             //below <-this->below    
if(board[0][0]==board[0][1] && board[0][1]==board[0][2] && board[0][2]==board[0][3])
{
    board[0][0]=6;
    board[0][1]=6;  
    board[0][2]=6;
    board[0][3]=6;   // brute force would require many more to complete 
}
```

I know there must exist a much more elegant approach than listing out all permutations. If you have seen this and recall the technique I would very much appreciate your assistance. C-Monster

Comment: @ciphermagi You have an option to edit the question. But that would be too much work wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Not too much at all. Just got confused whether there should be eight (8) or four (4) spaces. All good now, I think.

Comment: What do you mean a more elegant way. You have to go through all elements, there is not any other way.

Comment: What you're doing really depends on what you mean by 3 or more adjacent. Do they have to be in a straight line, can they be diagonal, etc.? Aside from that, I would recommend a moving "window," similar to the way you would check nearby elements in a minesweeper game array to find out how many adjacent "bombs" there are.

Comment: I was stoked when I first read this as it seems like a good plan of attack, similar to the crypto implementation. But, it's turning out to be more complexity than what is called for it seems. You wouldn't happen to have any similar suggestions would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very suitable to do in SIMD manner, since SIMD will do compare oprations on continuous data in parallel. This approach will run significantly faster than any kind of plain C code.
I assumed your `board[][]` has `int` type. There is a example for you which works fine on my MinGW. You need to include a header `intrin.h` or `emmintrin.h` for SSE2 intrinsics.
You can replace all `10` in the code to resize `board`.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main(){
    int board[10][10];
    int row, col;
    for(row=0;row<10;row++){
        for(col=0;col<10;col++){
            board[row][col]=rand()%2+1; //filling matrix here
            printf("%d ", board[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(row=0;row<10;row++){
        col = 0;
        while(col <= 10 - 4){
            __m128i xmm0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&board[row][col]);
            __m128i xmm1 = _mm_set1_epi32(board[row][col]);
            __m128i xmm2;
            __m128i xmm6 = _mm_set1_epi32(6);
            __m128i xmmn = _mm_set1_epi32(-1);
            unsigned long c;
            int mask;

            xmm0 = _mm_xor_si128(_mm_cmpeq_epi32( xmm0, xmm1 ), xmmn);
            mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(xmm0);
            if (!mask){
                _mm_storeu_si128( (__m128i*)&board[row][col], xmm6 );
                col += 4;
                do{
                    if (col > 10 - 4) col = 10 - 4;
                    xmm0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&board[row][col]);
                    xmm2 = _mm_or_si128( _mm_cmpeq_epi8( xmm0, xmm1 ), _mm_cmpeq_epi8( xmm0, xmm6 ) );
                    xmm0 = _mm_xor_si128(xmm2, xmmn);
                    xmm0 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(xmm0, 4), xmm0);
                    xmm0 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(xmm0, 8), xmm0);
                    xmm2 = _mm_xor_si128(xmm0, xmmn);
                    _mm_maskmoveu_si128( _mm_set1_epi32(6), xmm2 , (char*)&board[row][col] );
                    mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(xmm0);
                    if (col == 10 - 4){
                        col++;
                        break;
                    }
                    c = __builtin_ctz(mask);/* In MSVC: _BitScanForward(mask, &c); */
                    c >>= 2;
                    col += c;
                }while(mask);
            }else{
                col += __builtin_ctz(mask) >> 2;
            }
        }
    }
    for(row=0;row<10;row++){
        for(col=0;col<10;col++){
            printf("%d ", board[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This looks excellent. Which functions do I need to declare? Thank you very much.

Comment: This looks excellent. Really, very good. Would you mind explaining a little more how you set this up? I need to declare mask obviously, and what else? While many people are knit picking formatting others are offering elegant solutions.

Comment: @C-Monster: I don't know which platform you are working on. I pasted whole test program here which may be helpful. Functions prefixed by `_mm_` are "intrinsics", you can directly call them as long as you included the header.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on Sandy i7 x86 gcc under Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I would very much like to get this working so that I can thoroughly understand it.

Comment: You know what, I am working inside a VM and GCC is reporting that SSE 2 is not enabled. Very disappointing.

Comment: @C-Monster: You could try use "-march=corei7" option of GCC. Should compile.

Comment: It did. Again, this is a long, long way from complaining about formatting. Thank you very much for your time. -C-Monster

Comment: Incredibly fast and works perfectly. Aean, one last question. Could you refer me to where I could read about the functions used in this code. I assume it's probably Intel documentation.

Comment: @C-Monster: I learned to use them by reading MSDN. These are compiler built-in, so look for them on your compiler documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcwz153a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @ Aean, this is very cool. I have been learning how to use it and it seems that the code should be identical to access the vertical matches except that col should be switched to row. But it doesn't seem to work. You wouldn't have any suggestions would you?

Comment: No, it's not such a simple work. It's about the data structure you used to represent your board. Here SIMD load data horizontally so it's totally different to do matches in horizontal and in vertical ( and diagonal, some times). What's more, If you want vertical matches it must get done at the same time with horizontal, since either matches will make changes to the board, if you match two directions sequential you'll lose which number the piece '6' was before, then fail to recognize all shapes with "cross".

Comment: I would say, try to hold two board arrays in memory, such as one `board_v` and one `board_h`, update them simultaneously and incrementally. If you can, reduce type of board arrays from 'int' to 'char' so a whole strip board will fit in one XMM register and things will get much simpler. Data structure is so important in game programs. This site may help: http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Board+Representation

Comment: That did it. The program is running. Of course, the horizontal checks are much faster than the vertical but was able to check y in O(n). Thank you so, so much. I have learned a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is more elegant way to implement it, I am providing what I do now.

1. If you want to get [1,5], use rand()%5+1.
2. The example just show 1
       direction, from left to right by row, you need to consider the
       column and diagonal if you need, note you may need a status array to
       mark if the element was compared or not.
3. One optimization, if the
       adjacent elements is different, do not need compare the behind
       elements, start from the new one. For example, if `a[0][0]==a[0][1] && a[0][1] != a[0][2]`, do not need compare a[0][1] and a[0][3-9], start from compare a[0][2] and a[0][3-9].

`

```
int main()
{
    int board[10][10];
    int row=0,col=0;
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    for (row=0;row<10;++row)
    {
        for(col=0;col<10;++col)
        {
            board[row][col] = rand()%5 + 1;
            printf("%d ", board[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int count = 1;
    int seek = 0;
    for(row=0;row<10;++row)
    {
        for(col=1;col<8;++col) //compare at least 3 elements
        {
            for(seek=col+1;seek<10;)
            {
                if(board[row][col] == board[row][seek])
                {
                    ++count;
                    ++seek;
                }
                else
                {
                    col = seek-1;
                    break; //change the start element
                }
            }
            if (count >= 3)
            {
                //print the found location
                //printf("%d  %d\n", row, seek-1);
                int i;
                for(i=seek-1;count>=1;--count)
                    board[row][i--] = 6;
            }
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    //print the result
    for (row=0;row<10;++row)
    {
        for(col=0;col<10;++col)
        {
            printf("%d ", board[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

For each row, scan across the columns.  Read an element, and scan forward over columns until you either reach the last column, or you find an element with a different value.  If the length of the span is greater or equal to 3, go back and set all the elements to 6.  If you haven't reached the last column, continue scanning from the element that caused you to stop.